# Encontrar si números consecutivos en un array están separados por la misma magnitud

Tags: java, array

tengo que hacer esto:
Realiza una función o método que reciba un arreglo de números y detecte si todos los números en posición consecutiva están separados por la misma magnitud pero al momento de validar me lo regresa con un verdadero en vez de falso.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ar[]={194, 54, 23, 7, 3, 6, 8};
    if(array(ar)){
        System.out.println("Son consecutivos");
    }else{
        System.out.println("No son consecutivos");
    }
}

public static boolean array(int arr[]){
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] + 1 != arr[i] + 1){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en el condicional , ya que lo tienes  mal planteado

```
  if(arr[i] + 1 != arr[i] + 1){
        return false;
    }
```

y nunca se cumple la condicion, por lo tanto , el codigo siempre llega hasta el final del metodo ejecutando el return true

fijate que le dices

**si (la suma de 1 mas el valor guardado en la posicion del array con indice=i) es diferente  a  (la suma de 1 mas el valor guardado en la posicion del array con indice=i)**

que ejecute el return

Que quiero decir con esto , pues que en tu condicion le estas indicando, que si el valor guardado en una posicion es diferente al valor guardado en la misma posicion que ejecute un codigo.... por lo tanto, nunca se cumple , ya que el valor de una posicion siempre sera igual que el valor de la misma posicion.....lo correcto es esto:

```
 if((arr[i] + 1) != arr[i+1]) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está dado por tu condición:

```
if(arr[i] + 1 != arr[i] + 1){
        return false;
    }
```

Esta condición siempre arrojará `false` y por lo tanto no entrará al **bloque if**.

Haré el ejemplo con tus números:

```
  int ar[]={194, 54, 23, 7, 3, 6, 8};
```

Al usar `Arrays.sort(arr);` quedarán así:

```
{3, 6, 7, 8, 23, 54, 194};
```

Si `i = 0`, entonces: `arr[i] + 1` es igual a: 3 + 1 != 3 + 1, realizando la operación (suma): 4 != 4 **retorna** `false`. Y así sucesivamente por cada iteración `i < arr.length;` estarías comparando los mismos números.

Por lo tanto, terminará el ciclo, y retornará siempre `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que han comentado es correcto, tú validación la puedes cambiar identificando el valor de la posición 0 y 1 para despues hacer una resta y con ello obtendrás la magnitud, posteriormente haces la validación para las demás posiciones.

```
Arrays.sort(arr);  // en este punto estás ordenando tu arreglo
int valorAux= 0;  // este auxiliar nos servirá para identificar la magnitud 
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

    if(i== 0){  // solo en la primera iteración  extraeremos la magnitud
       valorAux= arr[i+1] -  arr[i] ;  // cómo está ordenado ascendente mente el valor de la posición 1 es mayor que el de la posición 0
    }

    if( (i== arr.length-1)  && (arr[i+1] -  arr[i]  != valorAux)){  // aquí validamos primero que el valor de i sea igual a la longitud menos 1 ya que se empieza por 0. También se válida el valor de la posición con i más 1 ya que es el número siguiente en la iteración, menos el valor de la posición actual sea diferente del valor de la magnitud
            return false;
     }

   return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que yo entiendo del problema lo que te pide es que esta condicion sea verdadera 
              array[i+1]-array[i]==array[1]-array[0]
Y esta se tiene que cumplir para todo i>1.
Por ejemplo si tienes el arreglo:
               int[] array={1,3,5,7,9}
Este cumple la condicion ya que todos estan separados por la misma cantidad, que es dos, ya que:
1-3=5-3=7-5=9-7=2
Saludos
Dios los bendiga